# Command-line jade "Cannot read property"

Tags: node.js, pug

Running through [this useful walkthrough](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) for Node.js authentication with Passport, but utilising Jade templating rather than ejs.  When actually running the app, the correct values are displayed in the HTML, but it annoys me that command-line jade complains.  Any ideas why?

Here is the calling code:

```
exports.myAccount = function (req, res) {
    res.render('myAccount', {
        title: 'Welcome back.',
        user: req.user
    })
};
```

... and a snippet of the Jade file (myAccount.jade) :

```
div.row
    div.col-sm-6
        div.well
            h3
                span(class="fa fa-user")
                | Local
            p
                strong id
                | : #{user._id}
                br
                strong Username
                | : #{user.local.username}
```

Finally, the error when running Jade is:

```
TypeError: myAccount.jade:22
    20|                         p
    21|                             strong id
  > 22|                             | : #{user._id}
    23|                             br
    24|                             strong Username
    25|                             | : #{user.local.username}

Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (..../lib/jade.js:172:8), <anonymous>:138:49)
```

As already mentioned, the values *do* actually render, so how do I get Jade to quit complaining??

adv-THANKS-ance

Comment: Should note, I'm using WebStorm, with the Jade file-watcher, which is why it annoys me (as it pops up at the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: provide some data on the command line so jade can properly render your string interpolation expressions such as `#{user._id}`.

```
jade --obj '{"user": {"_id": "42", "local": {"username": "bob"}}}' myAccount.jade
```

Explanation: Jade takes 2 things as input: some jade syntax plus some data. In your app, the data is provided by your code taking `req.user`, etc, so jade has what it needs to render the template to HTML. On the command line, there's no data there, so you have to provide it as I've done above.

**Bonus Tip:** There's more concise ways to express your template without so many pipes:

```
div.row
  div.col-sm-6
    div.well
      h3
        span.fa.fa-user Local
      p
        strong= "id: #{user._id}"
        br
        strong= "Username: #{user.local.username}"
```

Comment: It's that simple.  Thanks Peter.  As an afterthought therefore, it might not be possible to do as you've suggested using WebStorm's file-watcher?  At least, I cannot provide a generic --obj switch that would work for all my files...